# Receiving "Kernal Error" for reinstallation of Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, macos-catalina

Like many, I have reinstalled Anaconda after upgrading to MacOS Catalina.   I did not 'uninstall' but deleted the folder (I am not a power user but an occasional user of python).

I did a clean install of Anaconda 3, and updated python to Python 3.8.  When I start a notebook, I get the error message "Kernal Error."
[image]

Clicking on the "Kernal Error" button, I see the following message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Glenn/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1703, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "/Users/Glenn/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/Users/Glenn/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 69, in post
    model = yield maybe_future(
  File "/Users/Glenn/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/Glenn/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/Users/Glenn/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "/Users/Glenn/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/Glenn/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/Users/Glenn/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 100, in start_kernel_for_session
    kernel_id = yield maybe_future(
  File "/Users/Glenn/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/Glenn/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 176, in start_kernel
    kernel_id = await maybe_future(self.pinned_superclass.start_kernel(self, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/Glenn/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 186, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/Glenn/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 308, in start_kernel
    self.kernel = self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/Users/Glenn/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 215, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/Users/Glenn/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py", line 135, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Glenn/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Users/Glenn/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/anaconda2/envs/snakes/bin/python3'
```

But when I type 'python' in the terminal, I see that python 3.8 is installed:

[image]

Can anyone help me understand this better?   While I am at it, am I running the risk of confusion between this new anaconda installation and the initial one?

Comment: Could you type out the code/errors instead of including images?

Comment: @DanielWalker Done.